# Interrupting Prototype handler, alert() vs event.stop()

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

Here's the test page I'm using. This version works fine, forwarding to #success:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
</head><body>

<form id='form' method='POST' action='#fail'>
    <button id='button'>Oh my giddy aunt!</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var fn = function() {
        $('form').action = "#success";
        $('form').submit();
    }
    $('button').observe('mousedown', fn);
    </script>
</form>

</body></html>
```

If I empty the handler:

```
var fn = function() {
}
```

The form is submitted, but of course we are sent to #fail this time.

With an alert in the handler:

```
var fn = function() {
    alert("omg!");
}
```

The form is not submitted. This is awfully curious.

With `event.stop()`, which is supposed to prevent the browser taking the default action:

```
var fn = function(event) {
    event.stop();
}
```

We are sent to #fail.

So `alert()` is more effective at preventing a submission than `event.stop()`. What gives?

I'm using Firefox 3.6.3 and Prototype 1.6.0.3. This behaviour also appears in Prototype 1.6.1.

Comment: It looks like intercepting and stopping click as well as mousedown actually prevents the default action.

No idea why alert() behaves as it does, might be a browser issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the reason the form submission continued was because I wasn't also catching click.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that you are not able to stop the form submission using `Event.stop(event)` is because the event you are observing is the mousedown event, not a form.submit() event. I'm guessing the reason that the alert() prevents submission is because you have overwritten the default behaviour of mousedown on an input type="button"

Comment: Close, it seems the reason the form submission continued was because I wasn't also catching click. I still don't see the relevance of observing (not overwriting) mousedown has to alert().

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the 'e' in your event.stop needs to be capitalized (to read Event.stop(); )

Comment: I think that's true on IE, in FF events are passed in as arguments so the capitalisation should match the formal parameter, as it does :)